# .NET 4 side by side problem

Tags: .net-4.0, side-by-side

If the host program is compiled with .NET 4, but a referenced dll is .net 3.5.
Then the target deploy machine need to install both .net 4 framework and .net 3.5 framework runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in this case the target machine needs only the 4.0 framework runtime.